# How to calculate reflection profile of a beam shining onto a moving mirror?

Tags: optics, reflection

I want to build a projector, where a beam of light is shining on to mirrors, placed at different angles, which are spinning fast enough to draw lines. The question is, how to calculate the needed angles/distances/sizes to get the desired image output? Can anyone point in the right direction?
[image: Illustration (Side view) - (Top View)]

The goal is to get a line as shown in the top view. It needs to be N wide. In order to do that, I need to figure out how high the moving mirrors should be placed and at what angle. The same goes for the laser pointer. Also how big the mirrors should be.

Comment: How can one suggest something if you don't give some hint about the image you wish to create? Can you give more details?

Comment: Your diagram still isn't particularly clear, what way is the mirror oriented/spinning?

Comment: They are facing the beam and they are spinning along the circle, (each mirror should be at an angle to create more lines on the table).

Answer (score 1):

Simple geometry tells you that the size of the image $s$, for a given distance from mirror to screen $d$, is a function of angle according to

$$\tan\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{s}{2d}$$

For example, an image of 1 meter at a distance of 10 meters needs the mirror to sweep through an angle of $2 \cdot \tan^{-1}(0.05)\approx5.7°$

Answer (score 0):

The response time of the human eye is something like 60 Hz.  This means that you need to draw the full line in 1/60<sup>th</sup> of a second.  Based on your drawing (which isn't particularly clear) you are trying to draw a line using roughly 90° of mirror rotation.  Put this all together and you need the mirror to be rotating at an angular speed of 900 rotations per minute.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing, what should be the height of the mirror (dimension of the mirror)/laser and their angle in order to produce N width line on a table.